# Adding Discord API to React Native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, discord.js

I'm developing an Android app using React native for an client. He want's me to implement his discord server in newsfeed section of his app so thier logged users can see it even if they don't have discord server

So I'm asking...
Is there any discord API which I can implement in this react native project to show his server live updates in one of his app section even if user just logged in his app only but not in discord?

P.S. I'm unable to find anything related in discord documentations

Comment: have you see this link https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2

Comment: @MilanPansuriya I have, but couldn't find anything which can do the job that I asked in above. :'(

Comment: you want this https://discordapp.com/jobs in your app ?

Comment: @MilanPansuriya No! You got me wrong
I'm just saying tjat I couldn't find any topic in first link you sent which can show an specific discord server to my app newsfeed section :)

Comment: can you share discord page link so i can get idea!

Comment: Do you want to implement your channel news feed in your app?

Comment: @MilanPansuriya here I'm sharing an discord server url as an example https://discordbots.org/servers/327892735963037696 I just want this server to show all Thier updates and posts in my app newsfeed section. So my app I means my client app users can see it without even installing Discord seperately.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185884/discussion-between-milan-pansuriya-and-neha-sharma).

Comment: @MilanPansuriya yes you got it now. I want to implement my client channel newsfeed in his app newsfeed section so his users can see his discord server updates without even installing Discord app.

Comment: here you can get all the message from your channel but you have to design your own UI https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#get-channel-messages